# Heroku h10 issue now rails s wont work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Im having extreme difficulty getting my blog app to push to heroku and after searching forums and putting in different solutions it seems my app is pushing to heroku however showing the standard heroku application error

```
 Shawns-MacBook-Air-2:blog Shawn$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 1.21 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/ruby
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.1
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using rake 10.4.2
remote:        Using json 1.8.3
remote:        Using minitest 5.8.2
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using rack 1.5.5
remote:        Using mime-types 1.25.1
remote:        Using polyglot 0.3.5
remote:        Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.10
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Using execjs 2.6.0
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Using hike 1.2.3
remote:        Using multi_json 1.11.2
remote:        Using pg 0.18.4
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Using tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
remote:        Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.4
remote:        Using rdoc 4.2.0
remote:        Using sass 3.2.19
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using uglifier 2.7.2
remote:        Using treetop 1.4.15
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using warden 1.2.3
remote:        Using sprockets 2.12.4
remote:        Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Using activesupport 4.1.5
remote:        Using mail 2.5.4
remote:        Using sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Using actionview 4.1.5
remote:        Using activemodel 4.1.5
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.3.2
remote:        Using actionpack 4.1.5
remote:        Using activerecord 4.1.5
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.1.5
remote:        Using railties 4.1.5
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 2.3.3
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
remote:        Using devise 3.3.0
remote:        Using jquery-rails 3.1.4
remote:        Using rails 4.1.5
remote:        Using sass-rails 4.0.5
remote:        Using turbolinks 2.5.3
remote:        Bundle complete! 13 Gemfile dependencies, 50 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (0.34s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
remote: 
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> web
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, worker
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 29.8MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v10
remote:        https://hidden-island-1801.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/hidden-island-1801.git
   033bb79..ad0279d  master -> master
Shawns-MacBook-Air-2:blog Shawn$ heroku open
Opening hidden-island-1801... done
Shawns-MacBook-Air-2:blog Shawn$ heroku logs
2015-11-17T16:25:44.893903+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-17T16:25:44.732134+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v8 created by info@listedbyshawn.com
2015-11-17T16:25:44.732098+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 12501c4 by info@listedbyshawn.com
2015-11-17T16:25:44.853232+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-17T16:25:46.881436+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 5516 -e production`
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524318+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524233+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524322+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524350+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524353+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524356+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524348+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524357+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524365+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524387+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524386+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524354+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524391+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524354+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524363+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:125:in `print_boot_information'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524361+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:290:in `server'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524381+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524385+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524389+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524359+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524383+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2015-11-17T16:25:51.306312+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-17T16:25:51.118983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T16:26:05.106792+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hidden-island-1801.herokuapp.com request_id=96ba18f5-4f1f-4e78-89d1-d3751be690f2 fwd="72.231.3.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-17T16:31:52.946723+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-17T16:31:52.946714+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-17T16:31:52.792769+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 033bb79 by info@listedbyshawn.com
2015-11-17T16:31:52.792806+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by info@listedbyshawn.com
2015-11-17T16:31:52.893375+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-17T16:31:54.833297+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 29959 -e production`
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486880+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486903+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486907+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486905+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486908+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486907+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486906+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486911+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486905+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486910+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:64:in `start'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486907+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486909+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:112:in `print_boot_information'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486912+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486912+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486913+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486908+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486913+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486911+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486909+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `server'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.486911+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2015-11-17T16:31:58.499347+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-11-17T16:31:59.050411+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T16:31:59.050411+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-17T16:31:59.060355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-17T16:32:01.066955+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 57333 -e production`
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735743+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735756+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735758+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735758+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735759+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735760+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735760+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735761+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735763+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735764+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735765+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `server'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735765+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:112:in `print_boot_information'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735766+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:64:in `start'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735768+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735768+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735770+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735772+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735774+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735775+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.735777+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2015-11-17T16:32:05.756217+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2015-11-17T16:32:06.623851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-11-17T16:32:06.640663+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T16:33:32.518991+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hidden-island-1801.herokuapp.com request_id=eb68e24a-6c42-4ed5-a769-a0b83bf2430a fwd="72.231.3.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-11-17T16:51:11.373470+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy ad0279d by info@listedbyshawn.com
2015-11-17T16:51:11.373470+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by info@listedbyshawn.com
2015-11-17T16:51:11.577642+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2015-11-17T16:51:11.577653+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2015-11-17T16:51:12.500357+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-17T16:51:14.664864+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 31700 -e production`
2015-11-17T16:51:16.956013+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/bin/bundle: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
2015-11-17T16:51:16.956021+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/bin/bundle: line 3: `ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)'
2015-11-17T16:51:17.929349+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T16:51:17.929349+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-11-17T16:51:17.926872+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 2
2015-11-17T16:51:20.741615+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 6840 -e production`
2015-11-17T16:51:23.184902+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/bin/bundle: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
2015-11-17T16:51:23.184913+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/bin/bundle: line 3: `ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)'
2015-11-17T16:51:24.178529+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 2
2015-11-17T16:51:24.189642+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-11-17T16:51:34.709173+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=hidden-island-1801.herokuapp.com request_id=1aa74752-0743-4574-a4ef-934d3787d8f8 fwd="72.231.3.138" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
Shawns-MacBook-Air-2:blog Shawn$
```

here is my gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.1'

gem 'rails', '4.1.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.3.0'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :doc do
    gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0'
end
```

Guys seriously any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I am just starting out with ruby on rails and its been a legit 3 days I've been trying to figure this out

thanks in advanced

Answer (score 3):

Here's the error in your logs:

```
2015-11-17T16:25:50.524318+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
```

Just add the following to your gem file:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'thin' # added
end
```